# Have phase not equal 0 after 2 pi

Tags: python

if I have a list of phases for a sinusoidal data points and want to make a plot of time vs phase, the plot goes back to 0 after the data is past 2 pi. Is there a way I could manipulate the data so it continues after 2 pi?
I'm currently using phase = [i % 2*np.pi for i in phase], but this doesn't work.

This being about phase isn't important though. Lets say I had a list of data:

```
data = [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
```

But I didn't want the data to reset to 0 after 2, so I want the data to be:

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: define the phase as well ?

Comment: What "output" phase would you like to obtain for "input" phase 5π, for example?

Comment: As in the phase shift of the point on the sine curve. Such as Cos(pi) has a phase of pi.

Comment: Why are you using modulo if you want to have continuous output?

Comment: @dlask I would want 2π as my output, but right now I would recieve π because after 2π, the data will cycle to 0 again because the domain is [0,2π]

Comment: @ŁukaszR. I was using modulo because I was hoping I would receive the remainder, but didn't think about it hard enough. I see why that definitely won't work

Comment: `[i % 2*np.pi for i in phase]` won't yield the expected result. You have to add parentheses: `[i % (2*np.pi) for i in phase]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

If you use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), the de-facto standard math and array manipulation library for python, then just use [`numpy.unwrap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html).

If you want to do it yourself or for some reason not use numpy you can do this

```
def my_unwrap(phase):
    phase_diffs = [phase[i+1] - phase[i] for i in range(len(phases)-1)]
    unwrapped_phases = [phase[0]]
    previous_phase = phase[0]

    for phase_diff in phase_diffs:
        if abs(phase_diff) > pi:
            phase_diff += 2*pi
        previous_phase += phase_diff
        unwrapped_phases.append(previous_phase)

    return unwrapped
```

Seems to work in basic test cases.

Comment: @greenthumbtack Yeah, numpy is awesome. I've been using it for seven years and I still learn new things regularly.

Comment: Is it possible to change the wrap condition for np.unwrap? I realized my data is wrapping around π not 2π

Comment: Would I make the discount pi/2